# Laravel custom validator returns page instead of json

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, response, customvalidator

I made a controller to store tasks, it looks like:

```
    public function store(StoreTaskRequest $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validated();

        return response()->json($request);
    }
```

For the request validation i made a custom validator, that looks like

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreTaskRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'project_id' => 'required',
            'project_name' => 'required',
            'task_id' => 'required',
            'task_name' => 'required',
            'startDate' => 'required',
            'endDate' => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'project_id.required' => 'required!',
            'project_name.required' => 'required!',
            'task_id.required' => 'required!',
            'task_name.required' => 'required!',
            'startDate.required' => 'required!',
            'endDate.required' => 'required!',
        ];
    }
}
```

When i make a post request to that controller with incorrect data it returns an html page but when i post it with the correct data it returns the request as json

By the way i make my post request with: reqbin.com

```
Post request headers: 
X-Csrf-Token: ....
Content-Type: application/json

Post Params:
{
  "project_name": "Wiza",
  "task_id": 1,
  "task_name": "test 1",
  "startDate": {
    "week": 1,
    "start" : 11,
    "year": 2022
  },
  "endDate": {
     "week": 1,
    "start" : 11,
    "year": 2022
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why its returning a html page instead of an validation error?

Edit:

api.php is empty
web.php

```
Route::post('api/v1/tasks/', [TaskController::class, 'store']);

//Also tried
Route::resource('api/v1/tasks/', TaskController::class);
```

Comment: did you try to handle your error with a try catch statement

Comment: @Romylussone yeah i tried throwing an exception and returning an response()->json() in the catch but both still return a html page

Comment: Do you have any kind of middleware associated with the Route for this method that could be rendering a view instead? Might help to show your `routes/web.php` (or `api.php`, etc) file

Comment: according to the documentation, if there are a validation error then laravel automatically redirect to the previous page. so if you want to return an json file, you have to return a costumize response error as below : if($validator->fails())
    return response()->json(["errors" => $validator->errors()], 400);

Comment: @Romylussone That actually depends on the headers of the request being made; if the `content-type` is set to `application/json`, when the validation fails, it _should_ return a JSON response. I was going to comment the same thing, but the post shows that they are using that properly: `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: @TimLewis i added my web.php and api.php as edit

Comment: Have you tried adding an `X-Requested-With: XmlHttpRequest` header or an `Accept: application/json` header?

Comment: Could you please provide what html is returned when the data is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in your custom validator.

```
/**
 * Get the error messages for the defined validation rules.*
 * @return array
 */
protected function failedValidation(ValidationValidator $validator)
{
    throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json([
        'message' => implode('', collect($validator->errors())->first()),
        'status' => true
    ], 422));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem and below mentioned way works for me.

##### Header Debugging

First You need to verify the list of headers exists in your request. You can do this by following the below code in your controller `store` method:

```
 public function store(StoreTaskRequest $request)
    {
       dd($request->headers); //dump your headers exists in $request

       $validated = $request->validated();       
        return response()->json($request);
    }
```

and that will show you something like:

[image: request headers list in Laravel post request]

##### Solution:

Bestway and clean way to append those headers by using `middleware` i.e.
I've created `ForceJsonResponse` middleware.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ForceJsonResponse
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

after that, I've registered that middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php` as shown in the screenshot.

[image: register middleware by alias in Laravel]

then attach that `middleware` with that `route` as shown in the screenshot:

[image: attach middleware alias in route laravel]

[laravel doc reference for middleware attachement](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-middleware)

##### Worst case scenario

if still, it doesn't work then you can use `try catch` statement
[image: catch Laravel exception in catch statement]